# Resize icon by touch event

Tags: java, android

I would to do application that I can import a multi **icons** in the same view and I can **`resize`** each one of this icons by touch  , **`how I can resize icons by touch event ?`**.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to try this and scale your image use matrix class.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(),drawableId);
            int w = bmp.getWidth();
            int h = bmp.getHeight();


Matrix bMatrix = new Matrix();
            bMatrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h , bMatrix, true);
```

Comment: thank you but how i can resize bitmap in run time using touch event